# Update Formik field from asynchronous function outside form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a component that implements a simle Formik form. The component also has listeners for an event generated by clicking on a LeafletJS map. I would like to be able to update the *lat* and *lng* fields whenever the event handler is called so that they can optionally be filled by clicking on the map instead of entering values directly.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';


const FormComponent = () => {
    const onMapClick = e => {
        console.log(e.detail.lat, e.detail.lng);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('map:click', onMapClick);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('map:click', onMapClick);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{ username: 'guest', lat: 50.447243, lng: 30.524933 }}
            onSubmit={values => { console.log(values); }}
        >
            {() => (
                <Form id="test">
                    <Field type="text" name="username" />
                    <Field type="text" name="lat" />
                    <Field type="text" name="lng" />
                    <button type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </Form>
            )}
        </Formik>
    );
};

export default FormComponent;
```

I have come across the Formik `setFieldValue` function but this only seems to be accessible from within the form. Likewise I cannot use `UseEffect` within the form function.

I have had some success by changing the intial values and using `enableReinitialize` but this resets other fields unless I keep track of all fields and update the initial values on each change.

What would be the recommended way of acheiving this? I should add that the code is a trimmed down example. The real form has way more fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would make this.

Imagine that you have component with form, component with map and some parent component that contain both of them.

I would use some useState in parent component that will handle change of selected lat and lng and provide this data to my form.

Then in form I'll use useEffect, so whenever those data is changed it will `setFieldValue` in form.

All this stuff will look like that (abstract example):
Parent component

```
const [coords, setCoords] = useState(null)

return (
  <>
    <Form coords={coords} />
    <Map onChange={setCoords} />
  </>
)
```

Form

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(coords !== null) {
    setFieldValue("lat", coords.lat)
    setFieldValue("lng", coords.lng)
  }
}, [coords])
```

This should work because setFieldValue can set values for fields in every moment of time, even after initialization. I'm not sure what problems have you had with useEffect and setFieldValue, so if my answer didn't helped you, provide some more code examples

Comment: The problem that I am having, and I think applies to your code as well, is that you cannot define a useEffect within the Formik render function - it has to be at the top level of the component. But, setFieldValue is only available in the Formik render function, it cannot be accessed from the top level of the component.

Comment: Actually you can make what you want by creating a custom field for formik. You can have your input with lat and lng, and have a "select on map" button near that will open a modal window with map. That way you will have all necessary functions of formik inside of your map component to update formik fields values. Maybe this will help you?

Comment: The map component already exists and is permanently displayed in another part of the application. It emits events with the lat and lng when clicked. I am trying to get these into the form.

Comment: Okay, so what about this: You create custom field for lat and lng, and use useEffect with catching events inside of it, and also you pass down to those custom fields set field function. That way you will have your map where it is, and be able to set field values.